# How to get a specific index of a string?

Tags: string, if-statement

### Im currently working on something in JAVA, and i was wondering what is the best way to get a specific index of characters within a string..

Lets say I want to check something like that :

```
<title>Saturday - 14:00 GMT: Light Cloud, 3°C (37°F)</title>
```

How can I check the specific index of the String (GMT) to pass it to a switch statement and display the appropriate picture -> in that case "Light Cloud"??
Note that the day might change (bigger or smaller index will give different value so it shouldn't have a specific startPoint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String a = "<title>Saturday - 14:00 GMT: Light Cloud, 3°C (37°F)</title>";
a=a.split(": ")[1].split(",")[0];
```

Should do it. Splits by `:`, and then by `,`, to get light cloud.

Comment: Thanks @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 that was really helpful i used your code and everything its working perfectly.